# How to import a .sql file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, import

I am trying to import a .sql file using MySQL Workbench and I get this error:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 28: No database selected
```

I have first created an empty database called with the same name as the .sql file but it doesn't work.
I have also tried to do it with the mysql command client using:

```
mysqldump -u root database > file.sql
```

But it says a have an error in my SQL syntax. Furthermore, I don't know the path where I have to set the file.sql.

Comment: I was able to import mysqldump using the below mysql> use mydatabase;
mysql> source sql_file.sql;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

juergen d's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24372) is of course correct; however, considering your error message, you can also add to your SQL file at the beginning line like:

```
USE your_database_name;
```

This should also do the job and let you import under the Workbench.

When you are using `mysqldump`, the exported file will be saved in the current folder. It doesn't matter under what path it is. Just when importing from command line you need to be at the same folder or specify path to the file. But this isn't the case when you are using visual tool like Workbench, where you need to select the file from folder tree anyway.

Answer (score 71):

Export:

```
mysqldump -u username –-password=your_password database_name > file.sql
```

Import:

```
mysql -u username –-password=your_password database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: There has to be **no** space between `-p` and `password`

Comment: What if I don't have a password?

Comment: Then skip password parameter.

Comment: Piping (`mysqldump db -uuser -ppass|mysql new_db -uuser -ppass`) removes the need to use an intermediate file.

Comment: The database has to exist in MySQL for this to work, I think.

Comment: ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

Answer (score 43):

You can also import an .sql file as an already connected user to the database manner :

```
mysql> use your_database_name;

mysql> source file.sql;
```

Comment: source D:/path/file.sql; works superb! remember the front slash instead of back slash.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to import dump files when `source <filename>` doesn't work is to do the following:

**Dump**

`~> mysqldump --user=<user> --password=<password> <db_name> > <export_file_name>.sql`

**Import**

```
> mysql -u <user> -p <pass> <db_name>
mysql> USE <db_name>;  (if you didn't already select)
mysql> \. ~/<export_file_name>.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the password in command. Use the following.

```
mysql --u [username] --password=[password] [database name] < [dump file]
```

Comment: Database name is not required if the SQL file contains DB creation + `USE [database name]`.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, in the MySQL server installation directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5`), in the `my.ini file`, add the following line under `[mysqld]` in the server section:

```
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

And save the changes. (If you are not allowed to save, then copy and paste to desktop and edit again, then paste it in the same location.)

After that, restart your MySQL server.